# Eloquent relationship update appropriate database fields in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have BelongsTo model between 3 database (`Admins, vendors, and vendor_business_table`) table in Laravel. Trying to save the data which comes from HTML form in appropriate database field. My Admin Model looks like below:

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guard = 'admin';

    public function getVendorDetails(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

    public function getVendorBusinessDetails(){
        return $this->belongsTo(VendorBusinessDetails::class, 'vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

}
```

Once all the data is sent from the form I am trying to catch and save the fields. We have only `id` field is foreign key.

```
public function editVendorsDetails(Request $request,$id){
               
                if($request->isMethod('post')){
                $data = $request->all();
                   $myModel = Admin::with('getVendorDetails')->find($id);
                   $myModel->getVendorDetails->fill($data);
                   $myModel->getVendorDetails->save();
```

Once I save the form nothing is changed. Am I missing something here? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the `Laravel` version you're using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please replace your code with this code in ***editVendorDetails()***

```
if($request->isMethod('post')){
     $data = $request->all();
     $myModel = Admin::with('getVendorDetails')->find($id);
     $myModel->getVendorDetails()->create($data);
 }
```

Comment: Tried and got : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::craete()

Comment: Sorry, it's a spelling mistake. I have corrected it. It should be `create`. Please try now.

Comment: I have different fields returning back, would that be a problem ?

Comment: Are you returning the `Admin` model data? Also, is data inserted now properly?

Comment: I am getting an error as I mentioned above. Nothing is inserted. I mean values are staying as same. I have 3 table needs to be updated, Admins, Vendors and vendor_business_detail. In total I have 20 input data coming from form. I need to save all appropriate data to required table.

Comment: Sorry I just copied and pasted your code and you have misspelled "create" :) I have changed that and now it says : `General error: 1364 Field 'address' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Now, please check `$request->all();` or try `dd($request->all());` wheather the `address` data is coming or not.

Comment: And if I don't want the address is updated I have to delete "address" from the protected $fillable variable? Also should the name of form input should be the same of db table or that doesn't required?

Comment: Also, when we run "create" it inserts to the db, however I need to edit/update the existing data. Therefore I tried to use save(), but that did not work. can I use update() instead of create ?

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan have you ever read `Laravel` docs ?!

Comment: Yes, It should as you are not mentioning the field and data. If you want to keep a different name then you should use` create()` method like this way, 

`$myModel->getVendorDetails()->create(['database_field_name_1' => 'data_value_you_want_to_insert_1', ['database_field_name_2' => 'data_value_you_want_to_insert_2' ]);`

By this `create()` method a new row will be inserted. If you don't want to insert the address field just make the field nullable in the database or if you want to update the value instead of creating then just use the `update()` method instead of the `create()` method.

Comment: Thank you it now seems to work but I am still getting an error for other fields which is not in vendor table. I need to exclude them and according to the docuementation I have excluded them by `protected $fillable` variable in Vendor model. Am I need to do something else?

Comment: @MHHasib If I need to manually add all the field which comes with $data, then it is not practical at all. lets assume I have input names same as in DB fields, and what want is to put $data in update() and make it automatically retrieve the required fields.

Comment: You can use `$request->only([])` and pass the required data. Also May I see where you are getting errors?

Comment: The error is : `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`. This is because my $request covers all 3 DB table fields which comes from inputs. The update process should be done in all three table. Interestingly, in the same scenario when I use `$myModel->update($data);` instead of `$myModel->getVendorDetails()->create($data);` it works as expected (if the input name is same as in DB field name),  but why don't know. Furthermore, trying to understand if my input names are different than field name then should I do `update(['name'=>$data['differentinputname']` for all fields for 3 table?

Comment: I have not mentioned that in the case of using `$myModel->update($data);` I need to add `protected $fillable=['name']` to `Admin` model in order to make it work. This is also which I cant understand why we add this to Admin not to Vendor model? Also it creates a mess many fields and it will be more for another pages, what is the best approach ?

Comment: Because you are updating the vendor table.

Answer (score 0):

```
// fill this array which field you want to store like name
protected $fillable = ['name'];

or

protected $guarded = [];
```

Have a look at is [Mass Assignment Documantation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: I have added protected `$fillable` to vendors table but did not work. Should I add it to Admins or the mode which I am trying to save the fields? Is there another way, I mean not mass assignment but one by one?

Comment: Could you please show your `vendor` model?

Comment: `class Vendor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name','address','city','pincode','email','country','mobile'];
    //protected $table = 'vendors';
}
`